# Prevent browsers from using default/fallback fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, internationalization

I have a web app in which a user can change the font family of an input text area in a WSIWYG-kind style. Now, let's say the user inputs some Chinese text in the text area, but selects a Font that has no support for Chinese characters. In my application, I'd like the user to see those nasty squares (or something like that) that are usually shown when the font doesn't support the character. That way, the user would know that the font doesn't support the language and could choose a different one. The issue I'm having is that the browsers (Firefox 17 and Chrome 23) seem to render the Chinese part of the text with fonts (as Arial) that do support those Chinese characters, making the user believe that the font he's trying to use works fine.

Is there a way (I'm guessing through CSS) to prevent this? Is there a way of making the browsers not to be so "nice" for only this time?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe have a language selector on the site first and when that is selected it determines which fonts the user can select?

Comment: @Billy: Won't help; the font engine will substitute regardless.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams you'd be able to restrict the available fonts to fonts that don't require substitution.

Comment: @Enrico: How do you plan to enumerate them?

Comment: I don't plan to enumerate anything. Given the list of available fonts is known, it's trivial to verify which characters sets are supported for a given font.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can intercept the font substitution process by throwing in a catchall font, using some equivalent of `font-family: userChoice, yourCatchAll` where `yourCatchAll` is a font that has a generic glyph for all characters.

The problem is in finding such a font. The [LastResort](http://www.unicode.org/policies/lastresortfont_eula.html) font distributed by the Unicode Consortium would be ideal, since it also visually indicates the category of the character in broad terms, but its EULA does not seem to allow modifications. It is debatable whether this applies to the construction of web font formats (like .eot and .woff).

The [Unicode BMP Fallback Font](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=UnicodeBMPFallbackFont) appears to have more liberal rules of use, but it displays a character simply as its Unicode number in a box (and supports only Basic Multilingual Plane, though it contains all characters that most people ever heard of).

Comment: Hmmm... This looks promising, but the browser still seems to fallback to Arial. I'll keep trying, though! Thank you

Answer (score 19):

As the other answer already explained, the solution is to use a fallback font which includes 'all' unicode codepoints. However the difficult part was to find or built one which doesn't weight a few MBs.

A few years later there is now a more lightweight solution for a fallback font, the [NotDef font](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/adobe-notdef) by Adobe. It shows a box with a cross for 1,111,998 Unicode code points, is only about 22Kb and is using the SIL OPEN FONT LICENSE Version 1.1.

If you don't want to show anything there is also the [Adobe Blank font](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/adobe-blank).

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for. Do you know if this will work with emojis as well? That is if they put in an emoji char the little box will show instead? I'd answer for myself but don't have my laptop on me at the moment to try it out :)

Comment: To answer my own question, yes, this is a very graceful way to let people know that emojis won't work. It's not pretty, but it's honest.

Comment: On testing, it looks like NotDef font is becoming out of date? It doesn't block "" among other symbols. Or is that what the "1,111,998 Unicode code points" is talking about. It's not clear what it doesn't block. Adobe Blank has the same issue.